# Couldn't create ApplePay test wallet

Tags: ios, applepay

Apple has provided test cards details for ApplePay in https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox. However, I couldn't create a test wallet using these card numbers in my iPhone (iPhone 6 and iOS version 9.3.2, Region : UK). When I tried to create wallet using these card numbers, I received "Your Issuer Does Not Yet Offer Support for This Card" error message.

Please, can anyone suggest any solutions for create test wallets using the ApplePay test card numbers?

Comment: How did you manage to fix it ? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

> (iPhone 6 and iOS version 9.3.2, Region : UK

It's only supported on iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

To use the test credit cards, you need:

1. to create a sandbox icloud account to login to on the iphone (it's an iTunes connect sandbox test account referenced here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html )
2. login to that sandpit account on an iPhone or iPad running iOS 10 (you can do more testing with a Mac running macOS 10.12 too, in combination with the iOS device) (public beta available here https://beta.apple.com/ but as a developer you also have access to the private beta versions)